# finding sum of array elements using recursion

Tags: c

Finding sum of elements in an array using recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
  system("pause") or input loop */
int max(int a[],int b,int x)
{
    if(a[x]!='\0'){
        return a[x]+max(a,b,x+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[30],b,x,c;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(x=0;x<b;x++){
        scanf("%d",&a[x]);
    }
    x=0;
    c=max(a,b,0);
    printf("%d",c);
}
```

Input :10
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
expected output : 55
actual output : 102

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am not able to find error in my code can you help me out

Comment: The number zero and \0 are the same thing and will stop your recursion.  You want to check if X==b and return 0.

Comment: What is the true input?

Comment: I ran your code with b is 10, and the array is from 1 to 10. I get 55 in the output instead of 102 as you said. Is there any mistake here?

Comment: @NguyenCong are you sure of that because that's not the case at [my end](https://ideone.com/0082hI).

Comment: Not related to your problem, but just noting that max is a really poor choice of name for that function. Good and descriptive names will help you and others read and reason about your code as your codebase grows more complex.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
  system("pause") or input loop */
int max(int a[],int b,int x)
{
    if(x >= b)
        return 0;
    else {
        return a[x]+max(a,b,x+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[30],b,x,c;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(x=0;x<b;x++){
        scanf("%d",&a[x]);
    }
    x=0;
    c=max(a,b,0);
    printf("%d",c);
}
```

You just missed the recursion termination condition in the `max()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sumation(int array[],int i) {
static int k = 0;
if(k == 10) {
    return 0;
}

else {
    ++k;
    return array[i] + sumation(array, i+1);
}
}
int main() {

int array[10], size, sum;
scanf("%d",&size);
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    array[i] = i+1;
}

sum = sumation(array, 0);
printf("Sum:: %d ", sum);
return 0;
}
```

You can change the value of k eighter by giving the value of size variable to it, or just directly giving the value of the size constant in a base recursive case if block.